# Trying to insert a new row (without using table function) which will then copy the formulas and formatting from above while clearing the contents

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a section of code to this macro to copy that formulas and formatting from the above cells without the specific contents within the cells. I am not looking to create a table. The data ranges from A:T and ideally all formulas will go down into new row.

I have tried searching for so many different types of code but almost all of them are based on tables, which I do not intent to use.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    rowNum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", _
                                    Title:="Kutools for excel", Type:=1)
    Rows(rowNum & ":" & rowNum).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

I expect that the additional code will insert the correct formatting and formulas with the new row. The prompt where you enter the row should then take the row above the specified cell and copy the formatting and formulas.

Answer (score 0):

First you can straighten your code by using

```
Rows(rowNum).Insert Shift:= xlDown
```

Assuming you want to copy formats and formulas (non-constants) and dont mind other properties like validations to get copied as well you could use (I commented the `On Error Resume Next` statement - at least while testing).

Edit 1:

```
Dim rowNum As Long

'On Error Resume Next

rowNum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", _
                                    Title:="Kutools for excel", Type:=1)
If rowNum < 1 Then Exit Sub             

With Rows(rowNum)
    .Copy
    .Offset(1, 0).Insert
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents
End With
```

If you want to avoid using copy/paste in your code you could use:

```
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim cl As Range

'On Error Resume Next

rowNum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Row Number where you want to add a row:", _
                                    Title:="Kutools for excel", Type:=1)
If rowNum < 1 Then Exit Sub             'This code will fail if you act on rownum 1 - you could also show an error message to the user

With Rows(rowNum)
    .Offset(1, 0).Insert
    For Each cl In .SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
        cl.Offset(1, 0).Formula = cl.Formula
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How do these codes go together? When I try it does not insert a new row.

Comment: It does. The new row in my code is the row `rowNum` - using `rowNum-1` as copy reference. Looks like you want the user to enter the row **after** which you want the new row. Also I overlooked that you want to avoid copying constants. Will adjust the above code.

Comment: Hey, so I used the first edit but it is getting stopped at the offset. When I tried it the first time the code worked however not all the formulas were being dragged down and updated. Let me know if you need me to send you a section of the document to see what im talking about.

Comment: Can do - not sure how to send files between users on SO though.